# MapServer 7 PostGIS/PostgreSQL support

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapserver

I'm trying to compile MapServer 7 with:

- Proj 6
- Geos 3.7
- Gdal 2.4
- PostGIS 2.5
- PostgreSQL 10

But for some reason it complaining about `pg_config` not found, I usually insert the path `/usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_config` to compile software that need the same file but with MapServer 7 I can't

Here my cmake :

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt \
        -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/pgsql-10/bin:/usr/local/src/postgis-2.5.2:/usr/local:/opt:/usr/local/src \
        -DWITH_CLIENT_WFS=ON \
        -DWITH_CLIENT_WMS=ON \
        -DWITH_CURL=ON \
        -DWITH_SOS=ON \
        -DWITH_FCGI=0 \
        -DWITH_PERL=0 \
        -DWITH_RUBY=0 \
        -DWITH_JAVA=0 \
        -DWITH_CSHARP=0 \
        -DWITH_PYTHON=0 \
        -DWITH_SVGCAIRO=0 \
        -DWITH_FRIBIDI=0 \
        -DWITH_PROTOBUFC=0 \
        -DWITH_CAIRO=0 \
        -DWITH_HARFBUZZ=0 \
        -DWITH_ORACLESPATIAL=0 \
        -DWITH_MSSQL2008=0 \
        ../ >../configure.out.txt
```

I don't really understand why I can compile other software correctly and MapServer no, I don't even understand what should I put in the path as looking at this code (supposedly responsible for the check)

https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindPostgreSQL.cmake

this is the first error that appear:

```
Cmake Warning at cmake/FindPostgreSQL.cmake:21 (message)
Pg_config not found, will try some defaults
Call stacks (most recent call first):
cMakeLists.txt:755 (find_package)
```

and the second one is:

```
cMake error at CmakeLists.txt:73 (messages)
POSTGIS library/components/dependency could not be found.

HINTS:

-disable postgis...
- add cmake_prefix_path...
Call stack (most recent call firsts)
CMakeLists.txt:590 (report_optional_not_found)
```

How can I compile it with PostGIS support?

Comment: Note that a pattern of posting and deleting downvoted questions can result in suspension of your SE account.

Comment: Ok, sorry I will bear it in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer from the mapserver-users list in the end.

```
cmake3 -DINSTALL_LIB_DIR:PATH=/usr/lib64 \
       -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/lib64;/usr/pgsql-10" \
       -DWITH_CLIENT_WFS=ON \
       -DWITH_CLIENT_WMS=ON \
       -DWITH_POSTGIS=ON \
       -DWITH_CURL=ON \
       -DWITH_PROJ=ON \
       -DWITH_GEOS=ON \
       -DWITH_SOS=0 \
       -DWITH_FCGI=0 \
       -DWITH_PERL=0 \
       -DWITH_RUBY=0 \
       -DWITH_JAVA=0 \
       -DWITH_CSHARP=0 \
       -DWITH_PYTHON=0 \
       -DWITH_SVGCAIRO=0 \
       -DWITH_FRIBIDI=0 \
       -DWITH_PROTOBUFC=0 \
       -DWITH_CAIRO=0 \
       -DWITH_HARFBUZZ=0 \
       -DWITH_ORACLESPATIAL=0 \
       -DWITH_MSSQL2008=0 \
       ../ >../configure.out.txt
```

to notice the path in the `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=` are surrounded by `"`